# my php get request doesnt appear in the requested php file

Tags: php, html, get

Basically, I am trying to have a user click a button on one php page and it will print a new php page. This function WORKS. The problem is I am trying to have the userID transferred over to the 2nd page and printed on the new page. However, for some reason this seems to be getting lost. When I alert the user# right before the get request is made, the # shows pops up. But when the new page appears in the printer dialog, the userID is missing. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Function from php page 1:

```
$("#printing").on('click',function(){
    alert (user);
    $.get("flyer.php", {userNow: user});                
    $('body').append('<iframe src="flyer.php?userNow" id="printIFrame" name="printIFrame"></iframe>');
    $('#printIFrame').bind('load', 
        function() { 
            window.frames['printIFrame'].focus(); 
            window.frames['printIFrame'].print(); 
        }
    );
});
```

php page 2:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Tai Chi</h1>

        <h2>Sign Up Now!</h2>

        <h3>Benefits of Tai Chi:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>It enhances harmony between body and mind</li>
            <li>It improves your internal energy level</li>
            <li>Improves your muscle strength and endurance</li>
            <li>Reduces back pain</li>
            <li>Lowers daily stress</li>
            <li>Can slow down the aging process</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="contact">For more information, please email R-adler@neiu.edu</div>
        <div id="userID">
            <? echo UserID.$user = $_GET['userNow'] ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try this when you are calling your iFrame: `<iframe src="flyer.php?userNow='+user+'"`

Comment: @Sergio, thanks for the suggestion, but this did not work.

Comment: Did you remove the `$.get("flyer.php", {userNow: user});` when trying `<iframe src="flyer.php?userNow='+user+'"`? Btw is second file .php file?

Comment: Yes to both questions. (If you look at the code from the 2nd php page, youll notice the snippet of php at the bottom of the html). As to the first, if I remove the get, I assume I would remove it from the 2nd php page as well.

Comment: Try `<? echo $_GET['userNow'] ?>` in second page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to concatenate the user value like this:

```
$("#printing").on('click',function(){
alert (user);                 
$('body').append('<iframe src="flyer.php?userNow='+user+'" id="printIFrame" name="printIFrame"></iframe>');
$('#printIFrame').bind('load', 
    function() { 
        window.frames['printIFrame'].focus(); 
        window.frames['printIFrame'].print(); 
    }
);
});
```

Check also in the url if you get the `user`value passed there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no value being passed in the GET array.

Use the link as `flyer.php?userNow="+user`